# Changing data sources on the fly between cascading parameters

Tags: birt

I am trying to use BIRT to report on multiple projects spread across the company, each with its own JAMA instance, each with its own JAMA database.  My cascading parameter set is:

Project --> Release --> Test Plan

So the user selects the project, and only the releases for that project are shown.  User selects release, and only the testplans for that release are shown.  Report works great for each database, now I need to tweak BIRT to allow the user to select which database.

How do I create a cascading parameter set such that the first parameter is the datasource, and the subsequent parameters display data from the datasource selected in the first parameter?

Database --> Project --> Release --> Test Plan

Comment: Have you looked for a solution, I believe a solution for this has been posted [here BIRT @ SE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/birt) or at http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/

Comment: Looked for several days, saw some questions that flirted with what I want, and some solutions that answered the question with BIRT API called from Java.  But no native BIRT solution that altered the cascading parameter set based on a database selection in the first cascading parameter.